# How to say “There we go!” and “Lemme think...”

Tags: translation, word-choice

how would you say “There we go!” meaning you got what you wanted, it’s there, etc? and would “Lemme think...” just be 「そうですね…」？how would you translate that in an informal setting?

Answer (score 3):

These are all very difficult questions to answer. Japanese doesn't have direct translations from colloquial English phrases, and vice versa.

"There we go!" the way you use it could be:

「やった！」　- sounds more like "[I] did it!"

「こっち」　- translates to "this [one/way/place/etc.]" and would be used to point something out

「見つかった」　- translates to "found it"

「そうですね..」 is sort a general response when following along with a story in conversation, or after hearing some potentially new information, or agreeing with what someone says. It's sort of like "I see.." or "is that so..". It can definitely also be used to ponder for  a time before responding, but the meaning isn't explicitly "Let me think"

If you want to simply fill in time similar to "uhm..." in English, you could use 「えとー。。。」　or 「あのー。。。」. If you really need time to think, like you have to calculate or check your calendar or something you could say 「ちょっと待{ま}って」 or just 「ちょっと」　which is "Wait for a little bit"